# Cloudant/CouchDB Is it possible to create a view checking to see if there's any duplicates?

Tags: javascript, couchdb, cloudant

I have a view

```
function(doc) {
    if (doc.type == "XXXXX") {
            emit(doc.name, 1);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to change it so that the view only emits that doc.name if already doesn't exist? I'm fully aware that you have the reduce function; however, it still slows done the initial build of the view.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Check out [couchdb reduce grouping](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views#Grouping).  I think if your view did this for emit:

```
emit(doc_name,1)
```

and your reduce function was _sum, you could query this map/reduce view with group=true

Comment: I mentioned in my question that I'm aware of the reduce function, and I'm more looking for optimization on the initial building of the view.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand something about about reduce, this will still return all the results with a `_sum` value of 1 which the OP dose not want.

Comment: Correct, I only want one emit. Not a sum.

Comment: When calling the reduce include group=true.  Check out the reduce grouping documentation I tried to link to.  But I see what you are saying @dashservice.  You could use this query and then search for nodes where the count>1.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, the map function only has the context of the document that is passed into it. The only possible optimisation is an Erlang native view (or [Cloudant Query](https://cloudant.com/blog/introducing-cloudant-query) - note that reduce is not currently exposed though).